# Win32 application and Error 0xC0000007b due to 64-bit DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, openssl

I'm' trying to build a C++ application with Visual Studio 2015 using OpenSSL.
The application experiences a 0xC0000007b error with the message "The application was unable to start correctly". Using Dependency walker I saw my application, built as x86, uses the X64 OpenSSL DLL (in `System32` instead of `SYSWOW64`).

How can i force Visual Studio to use the 32-bits DLL?

**I just added these two dependencies :**

```
libeay32.lib
ssleay32.lib
```

And visual studio loads automatically ( or windows ? ) the 64 bits version, which gets me the 0xc0000007b error

Edit : Yeah, the DLL 32-bits are in the `SysWow64` too.

Any idea please ?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Don't directly jump to conclusions when you see System32 in the path. For x86 processes, Windows automatically substitutes SysWOW64 for System32.

Comment: You need to link in 32 bit openssl dlls. or compile for x64.

Comment: I just link the lib in the 32 bits openSSL.

Comment: @RustyX It's dependency walker who told me the dll used was the 64bits dll :\

Comment: Did you remember to use the 32 bits Dependency Walker? Because the 64 bits one looks for 64 bits DLLs.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot force Visual Studio to automatically find proper libraries for your architecture. Instead of it you should point to it explicitly via Library Path. Use `$(PlatformName)` there if you have multiple target platforms.

If you compile application as x86 than Windows automatically redirects you to the proper 32 bit system32 folder. But don't rely on it, deploy required OpenSSL dlls locally, into your application folder. If you have multiple target platforms it's also handy to use `$PlatformName` macros in post-build event. E.g:

```
copy "$(SolutionDir)3rdParty\OpenSSL\$(PlatformName)\ssleay32.dll" "$(TargetDir)"
copy "$(SolutionDir)3rdParty\OpenSSL\$(PlatformName)\libeay32.dll" "$(TargetDir)"
```